# Delete a item from a layout Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i need delete some items from a layout.

This is what i have
[image: First Image]

I already tried to hide them

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lblIBU).visibility = View.GONE
```

but looks like this
[image: Second Image]

I need the text on all the space

Comment: Do you need to hide the text but preserve the layout?  Have you tried View.INVISIBLE?

Comment: @Ryujin yep, still the same :(

Comment: Please, attach a layout. Also show, what fields should be retained and what should be hidden. This is not a problem of Kotlin.

Comment: change it from `View.GONE` to `View.INVISIBLE`